# Recuperar POST quando o nome do campo possui pontuação

Tags: php, post

Estou criando um formulário que possui um campo dessa forma:

```
<form name="form1">
  <select name="cmbitens.99">
    <option value="item 1">item1</option>
    <option value="item 2">item2</option>
    <option value="item 3">item3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Meu `name` no formulário tem "." (Precisa ser dessa forma pois estou utilizando, esse mesmo nome em uma aplicação do Google) quando vou carregar esse campo no PHP ele não me informa o valor do campo.

```
<?php
$valor = $_POST['cmbitens.99'];
echo $valor;

?>
```

Não estou conseguindo contornar esse obstaculo, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Mas você não está utilizando `POST` no seu formulário. Não faltou um `method="POST"` ali?

Comment: Eu só dei uma abreviada aqui para não ficar muito longo o texto, mas no meu código tem o método Post.

<form  name="form1" method="post" >
  <select name="cmbitens.99">
    <option value="item 1">item1</option>
    <option value="item 2">item2</option>
    <option value="item 3">item3</option>
  </select>
</form>

Comment: E qual é  resultado de `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: O var_dump deu a solução tbm, precisava só trocar "." por "_" no  meu php... Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) do PHP diz que os pontos (.) e espaços de uma variável são convertidos para *underline* (_).

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For
>   example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

Então o acesso a variável deve ocorrer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$valor = $_POST['cmbitens_99'];
echo $valor;

?>
```

---

Procure utilizar o hífen (-) ou *underline* (_) no lugar do ponto (.), pois isso evitará uma confusão na hora de utilizar o CSS e/ou JS.

```
<div id="user.name"></div>


/*
 * Está buscando um elemento que que contenha o id igual a "user"
 * e que tenha a classe igual a "name".
 */
const name = document.querySelector('#user.name');
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem agora... Obrigado !!

Comment: Dê nada! Fico feliz em ajudá-lo.

Comment: Comportamento funcionando na prática: https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-400307